# Verifying a matrix is Copositive

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

A symmetric matrix $A\in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is *copositive* if for every vector $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ with non-negative entries, we have
$$x^TAx \ge 0.$$

What are known methods to check if a specific matrix $A$ is copositive that are efficient in practice? I'm looking for something which will return an answer for a single instance of a 48x48 matrix in at most a week. I also wish for the implementation to not give false positive due to floating-errors, so I guess I am looking for a quadratic programming method which keeps track of its numerical precision/error bounds.

I have skimmed through this article: [A Variational Approach to Copositive Matrices](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/090750391?journalCode=siread). While it details various methods to check if a matrix is copositive, I am not too familiar with matrix algorithms and could not determine what the expected run times of these methods would be.

Comment: Checking copositivity is coNP-complete. You can find a reference to the proof in [this paper](https://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Roland.Hildebrand/c6classification/cop_cert.pdf), which also surveys methods for certifying copositivity.

Comment: I am familiar that it was coNP-complete, I nevertheless am looking for practical implementations. (i.e, week long run time for a single matrix of size 48) I will look at the methods outlined in your source, but since I am unfamiliar with the area, I don't trust myself to judge what ways are reasonable to implement.

Comment: It looks like you could check for such an $x$ with quadratic programming, so you could try applying on off-the-shelf quadratic programming solver.

Comment: I noticed that positive semidefiniteness is defined similarly to copositivity, and implies it. A matrix is positive semidefinite iff all of its eigenvalues are $\ge 0$, which can be easily checked.

Comment: copositivity is CoNP hard, as Yuval mentioned. the matrix in question has already been checked for semidefiniteness, which it is not.